# Mailx attaching multiple files using wild card

Tags: mailx

I am looking for Unix script where I can attach multiple files having similar name.

For e.g, on server I am having followings files:

```
output2019_1.txt
output2019_2.txt
output2019_3.txt
output2020_1.txt
```

---

```
echo "Hello" | mailx -a "test attachments" -a output2019* abc@gamil.com
```

Above script only attaching one file of 2019. I want all 3 files with 2019 should attach to email.

Please I am looking for actual attachment not some uuencode where it past on email body.

Comment: Firstly that needs to be `-A`, not `-a`. Secondly `mailx` doesn't support that - you'll need to write a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use brace-expansion in this way:

```
echo "Hello" | mailx -a "test attachments" '-aoutput2019_'{1..3}.txt abc@gamil.com
```

Comment: Thanks but none of them working:
echo Hello | mailx $(printf -- '-A %s ' output2019*) abc@gamil.com
Giving Following error:
Account output201901_1.txt does not exist

echo "Hello" | mailx -a "test attachments" '-aoutput2019_'{1..3}.txt abc@gamil.com
Giving Following error:
test attachments: No such file or directory

Comment: @Gujju error related to my answer is telling that file _"test attachments"_ doesn't exist which `mailx` command is trying to find and attach it to the mail but it finds no such file there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` and [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution):

```
echo Hello | mailx $(printf -- '-A %s ' output2019*) abc@gamil.com
```

The `--` tells printf that there are no more option arguments (otherwise it will complain about `-A` being an invalid option).  The `'-A %s '` is the format string, every remaining argument (the files matching `output2019*.txt`) will be printed using that format.  e.g. mailx would be run as:

```
mailx -A output2019_1.txt -A output2019_2.txt -A output2019_3.txt abc@gamil.com
```

---

Note: this won't work with all filenames - it will fail with filenames containing whitespace or shell metacharacters.  To cope with those, you can embed quotes in your format string.  e.g.

```
echo Hello | mailx $(printf -- "-A '%s' " output2019*) abc@gamil.com
```

This will work with filenames that contain any characters **except** single-quotes.

---

To work with filenames containing **ANY** valid character, you'd have to first create an array containing multiple pairs of -A options and filenames.  e.g. using [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) in `bash`:

```
mapfile -d '' -t attachments < \
  <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'output2019*' -printf '-A\0%p\0')

echo Hello | mailx "${attachments[@]}" abc@gamil.com
```

When bash expands an array like this (i.e. in double-quotes, with `[@]` as the index), **each element of the array is treated as a separate "word"**, and is not subject to any further word splitting or interpretation.

This requires GNU `find` (standard on Linux) for the `-printf` option.  Here we're telling `find` to output, for each filename, `-A`, a NUL, then the filename followed by another NUL.

The `mapfile` command populates an array from stdin, and we're telling it that NUL is the separator character (with `-d ''`)...and stdin is redirected (`<`) from `find ...` via process substitution.   See `help mapfile` in bash.  BTW, `readarray` is a synonym for `mapfile` in bash.

With the filenames in your example, this would populate the array `$attachments` with 6 elements:

```
$ declare -p attachments
declare -a attachments=([0]="-A" [1]="./output2019_1.txt" [2]="-A" [3]="./output2019_3.txt" [4]="-A" [5]="./output2019_2.txt")
```

IMO, this is the best version as it will work with any filenames.  It's a little more typing, but it's worth it.  It's always better to write scripts (and one-liners) defensively, always keeping "*what could go wrong?*" in mind and making sure that it won't.